# HTML Table size too big after mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-table

After I put the database values into the HTML table, the table gets to big. Any CSS code doesnt help. Shall I change something in the database value type? Or any other suggestion?

Below is the code:

```
<?php

  $connector = mysql_connect('localhost','root','')
      or die("Unable to connect");
    echo "Connections are made successfully::";
  $selected = mysql_select_db("user_registration", $connector)
    or die("Unable to connect");

  //execute the SQL query and return records
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login ORDER BY 1 DESC ");


  ?>

  <table class="table1" border="2"  >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surename</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Password</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
        echo
        "<tr >
          <td >{$row['id']}</td>
          <td>{$row['name']}</td>
          <td>{$row['surename']}</td>
          <td>{$row['email']}</td>
          <td>{$row['gender']}</td>
          <td>{$row['username']}</td>
          <td>{$row['password']}</td> 
        </tr>\n";
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
 <?php mysql_close($connector); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select a subset of your records, otherwise the page will grow as fast as the database table... use the `LIMIT` statement to get back a page at a time...

```
SELECT id, name, etc
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY id
LIMIT (0, 20)
```

The next page is

```
SELECT id, name, etc
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY id
LIMIT (20, 20)
```

And so on.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment but my issue is that the columns and the height of the table rows is too large (don't want to limit or anything). The table is okay first, once I fetch the data from database the table gets very large. Thanks!